# VBA Macro based on active range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a current macro as follows:

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MATCH"
    ActiveCell.Select
End Sub
```

However, this doesn't apply the "MATCH" text whenever I highlight a group of cells. I am brand new to VBA and was wondering how to achieve this while also running the macro with a highlighted range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to replace the text in the selected cells with the word 'MATCH'?

if so this will work:

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'
    Selection.Value = "MATCH"
End Sub
```

Note that `Selection` means all the cells you select and `ActiveCell` is the one highlighted within that (where your typing would go) - see [Application.ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834673.aspx)

If you're new to Excel, try calling up the Object Browser (press F2 in the code editor) which will let you look through all the different methods and objects available.